# Operation not permitted

Tags: permissions, osx, php

I'm on OS X and I'm trying to write an interface for for an interpreter, the communication with the interpreter looks like this in PHP:

```
$f = fopen('mmascript.m', 'w');
fwrite($f, "#!/Applications/mma/Contents/MacOS/MathematicaScript -script\n");
fwrite($f, 'Print[100]');
fclose($f);
chmod('mmascript.m', 0777);
passthru('mmascript.m', $error);
echo $error;
```

It displays error 127, "command not found". If I cd into that folder and try to run the file I get the error message

> bad interpreter: Operation not permitted

If I copy it to another folder, f.e. `cp ./mmascript.m ~/Desktop/mmascript.m`, it might give the same issue initially but will then magically start working. Since the path to the interpreter is absolute that should mean that the path is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: "If I cd into that folder" the folder containing the php script or the folder containing the MathematicaScript file?

Comment: @datUser Both the PHP script and mmascript.m are in the same folder.

Comment: can you try wit full path to 'mmascript.m' or with './mmascript.m' ?

Comment: @taliezin From the command line that gives the error I've been talking about; in the PHP code it now gives a more understandable error, 126, "Command invoked cannot execute" which indicates "Permission problem or command is not an executable."

Comment: I ment to change in your script where is 'mmascript.m' with '/path/mmascript.m' and you run php your_script.php ?

Comment: @taliezin Yes sorry, I meant "when I change it in the PHP code"; it's when I did what you suggested and changed to './mmascript.m' in the PHP code that I get error 126. Same thing if I use the full path.

Comment: sounds strange error 127 - _Possible problem with $PATH or a typo_, error 126 - _Permission problem or command is not an executable_, is your MathematicaScript with proper permisiions?

Comment: @taliezin This is the permissions it has: `-rwxr-xrwx` - I don't know much about permissions but that looks ok I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets add some Debugging Info, like so:

```
$f = fopen('mmascript.m', 'w');
echo "fopen complete."
fwrite($f, "#!/Applications/mma/Contents/MacOS/MathematicaScript -script\n");
echo "fwrite 1 complete."
fwrite($f, 'Print[100]');
echo "fwrite 2 complete.
fclose($f);
echo "close complete."
chmod('mmascript.m', 0777);
echo "Permissions Successfully Changed."
passthru('mmascript.m', $error);
echo "Passthru Complete."
echo $error;
```

My gut feeling is that passthru won't echo, because the passthru needs a command followed by your filename.

Comment: It returns "fopen complete.fwrite 1 complete.fwrite 2 complete.close complete.Permissions Successfully Changed.Passthru Complete.126" Also note that 126 is what passthru has assigned to $error, and passthru is not supposed to echo anything when it has thrown an error.

Comment: See [Error Gode 126](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884784/system-command-error-code-of-126).  As I suspected Passthru requires an executable followed by your filename.  See [PHP Passthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) man page

Comment: I have seen that, could you explain it to me? The parameter list reads: "command. The command that will be executed." `./mmascrip.m` is a command that works in the terminal sometimes, but often not as I described in my question. It shouldn't have anything to do with passthru since I'm getting the same thing if I execute the file in the terminal, no PHP involved.

Comment: If you want MathMatica to execute your script Passthru must look like `passthru('/path/to/mathmatica/mathmatica.exe mmascript.m', $error);`  The way your script is written passthru is treating your script as the executable, which it isn't.  Since it isnt executable the operation is not permitted.

Comment: I thought the shebang in the beginning of the file means that it is executable. It works your way if I call it from the terminal by `php -f test.php` - thank you! - however if I run it as a website on a local server then I get the error 1, which is a catch-all for all kinds of errors. So now I'm facing the problem of why it is working from the terminal but not in the browser. Could it be because the server is a different user, I'm told typically the server is 'www'?

Comment: The shebang at the beginning tells the shell its a script and to use a scripting language  noted in the shebang but your script relies on the passthru to Mathmatica to actually execute the Mathmatica Script.  The script you wrote should stop at `fclose` and then allow the user to download the completed Mathmatica Script.  Webservers typically don't have the Mathmatica binary on them.  As such, allowing a user to download it ensures that the user has Mathmatica on his local machine.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is build an interface in HTML with a form. I want to pass code through this form and I want the interpreted result to be shown in the HTML interface. All this will happen on my local machine. This is not working right now because passthru is returning 1 instead of the result, as it does when I execute the same file in the terminal.

Comment: In that case, you need to use PHP in combination with forms.  Research Form Submission with `GET` and `PUT`, then pass the script to Mathmatica using the passthru option like i wrote then have Mathmatica output HTML, and pass the html back to the browser.

Comment: I have that part nailed down, I have several years of experience with building PHP applications. The problem is only that passthru throws error 1 as I have said, instead of returning the result (if you reread my previous comments it should now be clear what I am trying to do and what the problem is, all taken together.)

Comment: You're still missing the point... Mathmatica must execute the script using the passthru option.  The resulting output must be saved by Mathmatica, and fed back to the webserver.  Mathmatica cannot directly process and output at the same time.  i.e mmascript must have output that can be rendered as html/php/asp/etc.  Think of Mathmatica as a Database.  In order to display data from a database on a website you must Fetch, Process if needed, and Output, So far you've only fetched and Processed.

Comment: Have a look at [WebMathmatica 3.3](http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/).  It already does what you're trying to do...

Comment: I've told you that everything happens on my local machine. I have a local instance of apache running on my computer. From a technical perspective it should not matter if I ask apache to execute the file  (by going to http://127.0.0.1:8080/evaluateMMA/index.php in the browser) or if I execute it manually via the terminal (php -f index.php), yet the former does not work and the latter does work.

Comment: I am also aware of webMathematica of course, but that's not what I want to do. I came here to ask about why my solution is not working and I still don't have a full answer. There is something wrong with the permissions or something which is causing passthru to return an error message, and that's what I want to sort out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23131/discussion-between-eyoung100-and-calle).